# In SUMIFS function I am getting #VALUE error

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function, sumifs

[image]

For the top table above, I am using the following SUMIFS function:

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$G$23,$A$3:$A$23,"=Cinthol",$B$3:$B$23,"=Bangalore")
```

to try to get the results in the output format shown, based on two criteria {1. Product and 2. City}.  But I am getting `#VALUE!` error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Is it possible that your locale require semicolons (;) and not commas (,) for separating parameters?

Comment: remove equal to sign in =Bangalore and  "=Cinthol"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>You have two issues.</strike> ["each criteria_range argument must contain the same number of rows and columns as the sum_range argument"](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/sumifs-function-HA010047504.aspx) <strike>and your criteria are `=Cinthol` and `=Bangalore`</strike>.

This may directly be addressed quite easily by repeating the SUMIFS function for each of ColumnsC:G individually (and you might then sum the results).

An alternative would be to add each row up in your data set and apply a PivotTable.

Comment: @pnuts Using an "=" sign in the criteria is not incorrect - change the sum range to a single column and the formula quoted in the question works as required.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `SUMPRODUCT` you can get the required result without adding any columns, e.g.

`=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$G$23*($A$3:$A$23="Cinthol")*($B$3:$B$23="Bangalore"))`

or with cell references to copy down a table

`=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$G$23*($A$3:$A$23=J2)*($B$3:$B$23=K2))`

That assumes that there are no text values (or "formula blanks" like "") in the range C3:G23. If there are then you can still make it work like this:

`=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$G$23,ISNUMBER($C$3:$G$23)*($A$3:$A$23=J2)*($B$3:$B$23=K2))`

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution:

First sum_range must be a column so instead of

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$**G**$23,$A$3:$A$23,"=Cinthol",$B$3:$B$23,"=Bangalore")
```

it should be

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$**C**$23,$A$3:$A$23,"=Cinthol",$B$3:$B$23,"=Bangalore")
```

to make it work.

If it's not enough you can use `=SUM(SUMIFS(), SUMIFS())`